# How to use AWK to print line with highest number?

Tags: linux, sed, awk

I have a question. Assuming I dump a file and do a grep for foo and comes out the result like this:

```
Foo-bar-120:'foo name 1'
Foo-bar-130:'foo name 2'
Foo-bar-1222:'foo name 3'
```

Etc.

All I want is trying to extract the foo name with largest number. For instance in this case, largest number is 1222 and the result I expect is `foo name 3`

Is there a easy way using awk and sed to achieve this? Rather than pull the number out line by line and loop through to find the largest number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I would do it. I just tested this in Cygwin. Hopefully it works under Linux as well. Put this into a file, such as `mycommand`:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {
        FS="-";
        max = 0;
        maxString = "";
}

{
        num = $3 + 0; # convert string to int
        if (num > max) {
                max = num;
                split($3, arr, "'");
                maxString = arr[2];
        }
}

END {
        print maxString;
}
```

Then make the file executable (`chmod 755 mycommand`). Now you can pipe whatever you want through it by typing, for example, `cat somefile | ./mycommand`.

Answer (score 3):

Code for [awk](/questions/tagged/awk):

```
awk -F[-:] '$3>a {a=$3; b=$4} END {print b}' file
```

---

```
$ cat file
Foo-bar-120:'foo name 1'
Foo-bar-130:'foo name 2'
Foo-bar-1222:'foo name 3'

$ awk -F[-:] '$3>a {a=$3; b=$4} END {print b}' file
'foo name 3'
```

Comment: +1 for a nice approach. It'd fail if the OPs data had a highest value of zero or less (`foo name -1`, `foo name 0`, etc) but that's probably not really an issue and is true of the selected answer as well.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the line format is as shown with 2 hyphens before "the number":

```
cut -d- -f3- | sort -rn | sed '1{s/^[0-9]\+://; q}'
```

Answer (score 1):

is this ok for you?

```
awk -F'[:-]' '{n=$(NF-1);if(n>m){v=$NF;m=n}}END{print v}'
```

with your data:

```
kent$  echo "Foo-bar-120:’foo name 1’
Foo-bar-130:’foo name 2’
Foo-bar-1222:’foo name 3’"|awk -F'[:-]' '{n=$(NF-1);if(n>m){v=$NF;m=n}}END{print v}'
’foo name 3’
```

P.S. I like the Field separator `[:-]`

Comment: This is pretty cryptic. Can you please explain what's going on?

Comment: which part you didn't understand, @PetreLamar ?

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk '{gsub(/.*:.|.$/,"")} (NR==1)||($NF>max){max=$NF; val=$0} END{print val}' file
foo name 3
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `grep`. you can use `awk` directly on your file as:

```
awk -F"[-:]" '/Foo/ && $3>prev{val=$NF;prev=$3}END{print val}' file
```